# "Open" vs. "open up"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, phrasal-verbs

Which of the following two variants is correct with reference to some email attachments?

> 1. I am unable to **open** them.
> 2. I am unable to **open up** them.

Answer (score 3):

The first option is correct:

> 1. I am unable to **open** them.

You could move the *up* in option two so that it reads *I am unable to open them up*, but the *up* is unnecessary in this sentence.

Comment: Can you please explain why it is unnecessary to change the second option to "*I am unable to open them up*"?

To me, the phrase "I am unable to open up them" sounds incredibly weird... I would have even called it wrong, if not for the fact that I would quite happily state that "I am unable to open up these things".

Comment: I meant only that if you were to insist on the word up, that would be how I would use it, but really it adds nothing to the statement

Comment: @bracho monacho: I'm with you. "open up them" sounds wrong to me, but "open up these things" sounds fine.

Answer (score 2):

Brevity should be the aim of email communication, and he better expression would be *I am unable to **open** it*.

The meaning of this would be obvious to an email user, and the extra word 'up' doesn't add anything.